# Showing this probability model sums to 1

Tags: probability, distributions, modeling

I am working through some exercises in an old SMP statistics book. I came across this problem which has me stumped;

Bags come off an aeroplane one by one. Suppose there are $n$ pieces of baggage on the aircraft, of which $r$ belong to me, then the probability that my last bag is the $k^{th}$ to appear is

$\frac{r(n-r)!}{n!}*(k-1)(k-2)..(k-r+1)$

I get the model above. Since there in total $n!$ combinations of bags - and of these $r$ have the last bag in the $k^{th}$ position. The other bags, $r-1$, can be placed in $(k-1)(k-2)..(k-r+1)$ ways and that leaves all the other bags to be placed in $(n-r)!$ ways.

However by running through values of $k$ from $r$ to $n$ how can I check that this gives a total probability of 1.

I have tried some numerical examples with $n=10$ and $r=3$ for instance and I ca see the patter emerges for $1*2$, $2*3$, $3*4$...$8*9$ for the $(k-1)(k-2)..(k-r+1)$ part of the model - since this is the only non-constant part when summing. But how can I show algebraically this holds for all $r$ and $n$. Many thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Use Pascal's triangle to sum $(k-1)\cdots (k-r+1)/(r-1)!$ for $k$ up to and including $n.$

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow. Would be able to elaborate a little more? Many thanks

Comment: Some people call this the [hockey stick identity](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Comment: Thanks @whuber cracked it now. It becomes $(\frac{n}{r-1})$ and take it from there

Comment: That is, without the line going across the middle! I could do with work on my Latex too!